# Haystack and Solr searching term containing "-"

Tags: python, solr, django-haystack

While searching terms containing the character '-' I don't get any results. For example:

I search for term "e-shop" and the stored_fields are : 
{ 'url' : u'http://www.e-shop.com/', 'text': u'E-shop\nTechnology\n', 'name': u'E-shop'}

the search_index.py is :

```
class ShopIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    url = indexes.CharField(model_attr='url')
```

I am using Solr.

Do you know if I have to somehow escape this character, whether I need to store in a different way or If I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/apache/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-6.1.pdf

You need to check `edge_ngram` field declaration in your `schema.xml`, I assume that by default in haystack `EdgeNgramField` has filter in its schema declaration which splits word by letter case and `-`, so when field value is e.g `e-shop`, solr builds tokens like `e`, `s`, `sh` and so on.
One more thing: https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/templates/search_configuration/solr.xml#L120

by default haystack has `minGramSize="2"` so in this case there is no way for searching by single character. In  order to search by single character change its value to `"1"`